# call an SQL User Defined Function Within another User Defined Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, function

I have the following UDF which i want to call another udf that split the result on return

```
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnGetValueForEmployeeTable]
(   
    @EeID       AS int,
    @ProvisionID    AS int,
    @optionName     AS varchar(4000)
)
RETURNS varchar(128)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
    WHERE  
    RETURN **call here this function** GetOptionValueFromOtherOptions(@optionName ,  @value `this is the value from select` )
```

Is it possible ? if yes how?

Comment: Well, maybe an absurd question, but why don't you just call the inner function instead of nesting them, or use a synonym? What does nesting them buy you except a maintenance headaches and even further restricting optimization?

Comment: well cos the other function is already existing and used for separate functionality too .. but i see your point here. I am not familiar with UDFS and honestly never thought about nesting them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
declare @retval varchar(128);

select . . .;

select @retval = GetOptionValueFromOtherOptions(@optionName ,  @value);

return @retval;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RETURN (SELECT dbo.GetOptionValueFromOtherOptions(@optionName, @value));
```

However I suggest this with extreme caution: UDFs are bad enough on their own; nesting them will only compound the issue. Probably better to make the code that requires one function vs. the other to call them directly instead of using this nesting approach.